# Property or method "attrs" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

i have this error when i press a button which its inside a v-tooltip, it should sends me to anothe page in web site:

```
          <v-tooltip bottom mg="1">
              <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                <router-link
                  :to="{
                    name: 'trabajosObservaciones',
                    params: { datos: item },
                  }"
                >
                  <v-btn
                    v-bind="attrs"
                    v-on="on"
                    color="orange"
                    fab
                    x-small
                    dark
                    class="ml-2"
                  >
                    <v-icon>mdi-briefcase-eye</v-icon>
                  </v-btn>
                </router-link>
              </template>
              <span>Ver Trabajos</span>
            </v-tooltip>
```

how can i solve it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Error is not comming from this part of your code, it's in "src/app.vue"

probably using and unregistered data property in the template

Comment: so, do i  post my app.vue  file?

Comment: If you like you can put it on github so i could take a look